# Python script to automate data update

Tags: arcpy, append, error-000840

I am trying to update parcel data for 29 different counties. Typically I would truncate the old data and append the new data, but clicking both those commands 29 times is time consuming.

I have written a script to automate the process. Truncate works, but I am getting stuck on the Append command. I am getting:

> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Table View.
>
> ERROR 000840: The value
> is not a Raster Layer.

I think that the code is not recognizing the input value as individual feature classes and I am stuck on how to fix that. I am using a test environment with copies of 3 different counties.

```
import arcpy, os    
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "H:\Parcel Update Testing\Tax Parcels Test.gdb"

FCList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
inpt = "H:\Parcel Update Testing\2020.gdb" # do i need to spell out individual Feature classes? 
outLocation = r"H:\Parcel Update Testing\Tax parcels Test.gdb" 
schemaType = "NO_TEST"
fieldMappings = ""
subtype = ""
 
for fc in FCList:
    arcpy.TruncateTable_management(fc)
    print("Truncating Table")
 
for fc in FCList:
    arcpy.Append_management(inpt, outLocation, schemaType, fieldMappings, subtype)
    print("Appending Table")
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Append](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) documentation requires the following parameters:

```
Append_management (inputs, target, {schema_type}, {field_mapping}, {subtype})
```

Where `inputs` include:

> The input datasets whose data will be appended into the target
> dataset. Input datasets can be point, line, or polygon feature
> classes, tables, rasters, raster catalogs, annotation feature classes,
> or dimensions feature classes. Each input dataset must match the data
> type of the target dataset.

In your case, I see that you are specifying a geodatabase, but no feature classes, tables, rasters, raster catalogs, annotation feature classes, or dimensions feature classes. Same issue with the `target` parameter.

Additionally, you are looping through a list of feature classes, yet not applying the iterable `fc` to the Append tool.

Comment: So I would need to change the input and output to specific feature classes and type out an append command for each of the 29 different layers i need to update?

Comment: The `inputs` should be a list (e.g. `[featureclas1, featureclass2, featureclass3]`) of data. Also, you specified `r"H:\Parcel Update Testing\Tax parcels Test.gdb"` for the `target` parameter. This needs to be a single file (e.g. `r"H:\Parcel Update Testing\Tax parcels Test.gdb\some_featureclass"`) that matches the format of your input list.

Comment: Aaron is correct, the issue is you're attempting to output to a file geodatabase (workspace) where the tool expects a feature class or table to append the inputs onto. If you're creating a new feature class the tool you want is merge https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000 but your output still needs to be a feature class or table and not a workspace.